# Non blocking sockets in R?

Tags: r, sockets

I'm trying to use sockets to communicate between R sessions and can't get them to behave as the help file suggests they should (`?read.socket`).

In one Rstudio session I run the following

```
sock_server <- make.socket(port = 22222, server = TRUE)
write.socket(sock_server, "Ahoy-hoy")
```

and then in another I run

```
sock <- make.socket(port = 22222, server = FALSE)
read.socket(sock, loop = FALSE)
```

and I do indeed see the friendly greeting.

However, if I rerun the `read.socket` line without sending anything else it hangs, only returning when further information is sent. The option `loop = FALSE` is supposed to control this behaviour and presumably return an empty string if nothing is waiting to be read, but it doesn't change anything.

I've tried this on MacOS and Windows and it is the same in both cases.

Any ideas how to get sockets to behave?

---

I've now tried it with various combinations of RStudio, RGui, and R from the command line and it behaves the same in all of them as far as I can see.

My ultimate goal is to have something in R which can handle a FIX connection from an external host. It basically works using these socket functions, apart from the above issue which is very difficult to work around.

I'm open to using whatever else people use for these things.

---

Here's a second attempt which works! But unfortunately only on Mac, Windows does something strange.

Using a binary connection with a different set of socket functions in base R, on the server side you do

```
sock_server <- socketConnection(port = 22222, server = TRUE, open = 'a+b')
fix_message <- gsub("\\|","\001","8=FIX.4.4|9=106|35=0|34=1234|49=abc|56=def|10=999|")
writeBin(charToRaw(fix_message), sock_server)
```

and on the client

```
sock <- socketConnection(port = 22222, server = FALSE, open = 'a+b')
rawToChar(readBin(sock, raw(), n = 32))
```

Note that the message I'm sending has no newlines in it (this is a feature of FIX messages).

On a Mac this works as expected - running the `readBin` line twice gives you the whole message which you can paste back together, however on Windows the second part of the message vanishes!

```
# Mac
> rawToChar(readBin(sock, raw(), n = 32))
[1] "8=FIX.4.4\0019=106\00135=0\00134=1234\00149="
> rawToChar(readBin(sock, raw(), n = 32))
[1] "abc\00156=def\00110=999\001"

# Windows
> rawToChar(readBin(sock, raw(), n = 32))
[1] "8=FIX.4.4\0019=106\00135=0\00134=1234\00149="
> rawToChar(readBin(sock, raw(), n = 32))
[1] ""
```

I'm using R 4.0.2 on both platforms. Anyone have any ideas how to do this on Windows?

Comment: Just a guess:  are these socket functions compatible with Rstudio?  Have you tried running two Rgui.exe, or two terminal sessions to see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was pretty much a combination of the two methods above.

The server side does

```
sock_server <- socketConnection(port = 22222, server = TRUE, open = 'a+b')
fix_message <- gsub("\\|","\001","8=FIX.4.4|9=106|35=0|34=1234|49=abc|56=def|10=999|")
writeBin(charToRaw(fix_message), sock_server)
```

and the client side does

```
sock <- socketConnection(port = 22222, server = FALSE, blocking = FALSE, open = 'a+b')
readLines(sock, warn = FALSE)
#> [1] "8=FIX.4.4\0019=106\00135=0\00134=1234\00149=abc\00156=def\00110=999\001"
readLines(sock, warn = FALSE)
#> character(0)
```

No lost messages, no blocking, and it works on both the Mac and Windows machines I've been using.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried future package :

```
library("future")
plan(multiprocess)


mySocketRead<- function()
{
  sock <- make.socket(port = 22222, server = FALSE)
  msg <-read.socket(sock, loop = FALSE)
  #print(msg)
  print("read done ")
}


# normal non-blocking
res %<-% mySocketRead()

print("here we go")
```

But this example is also blocking while read, so it seems to be an general problem of the read.socket function.

*I got 2 more ideas:*

**idea A:** maybe you exchange your server and client with each other, because if the server is always blocking in an forever read loop it could be more acceptable, but this depends on your usecase.

**idea B:** use the socketConnection implementation and transform the string you
want to send, to something less problematic string.
I do think, your "lost string" from mac to windows appears, because you do use "4\0019" string literals, which could might be “interpreted” wrong by different socket implementation.
In general its useful to maybe use the base64encode and base64decode functions
maybe you should also add an checksum to ensure your transmission was succesful.

```
require(base64enc)

#send
fix_message <- gsub("\\|","001","8=FIX.4.4|9=106|35=0|34=1234|49=abc|56=def|10=999|")
fix_message_base64 <- base64encode(charToRaw(fix_message))
writeBin(charToRaw(fix_message_base64), sock_server)

#receive
fix_message_input_base64_raw <-readBin(sock, raw(), n = 32)
fix_message_input_raw <-base64decode(fix_message_base64)
fix_message_input <-rawToChar(fix_message_input_raw)
```

if this is not helful, you could might debug your network traffic with [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

Old not working but is an example howto wait X seconds for function Y to finsish :

<s>I would think use socket inside a function and wait until this function timeout. This will be also blocking, but not for ever.</s>

```
require(R.utils)

## function that can take a long time
socketRead<- function()
{
    sock <- make.socket(port = 22222, server = FALSE)
    read.socket(sock, loop = FALSE)
    return("read")
}

# call read function
waitingTimeInSeconds=10
withTimeout(socketRead(), timeout = waitingTimeInSeconds, onTimeout = "error")
```

find the docu of the function withTimout [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.10.1/topics/withTimeout)

Comment: Nice idea, but this doesn't work for me - it still just hangs. I tried it with the `make.socket()` outside of the `withTimeout()` call. I also tried it with `Sys.sleep(100)` where it does interrupt after 10 seconds.

Comment: I don't think the null characters (`\001`) are the problem. I tried with the base64 endcoding/decoding and it has the same problem - it's fine on the mac, but on the Windows machine if the remaining message to read is shorter than `n=32` then it gets lost. I suppose I could  set `n=1` but this feels like a stupid solution and I'm hoping for a better one.

Comment: Does it need to be a fixed length or could you just use `socketConnection` and `readLines`, similar to the solution found here: https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/read-socket-utils-package-something-is-going-wrong-td4531374.html

Comment: maybe you fill find your answer, when you figure out, at what point (transmission, conversion, ..) you string gets trimmed, you could use wireshark to observe what information are transfered via the socket

Comment: @t2solve I had a play with wireshark and it looks like the message is sent. It must be being discarded by `readBin` somehow. Not sure how to investigate what is read from the socket using wireshark.

Comment: @Roger-123 That is the same issue, but it looks like the messages he sends have newlines in. I had to use a binary connection `open = 'a+b'` in order to send messages with writeBin without newlines. Oh. It seems `readLines` does still work with binary connections! And it neither blocks nor trims the message, and you can turn off the warnings. Easy bounty here if anyone wants to write that up...